# Image processing: Mac Preview Auto level

Tags: macos, image-processing

I want to enhance the quality of a badly captured fingerprint. I used Mac 's Preview App. Opened Tools -> Adjust Color -> Auto Level

It worked like magic on a grayscale image. Wanted to know what image processing algorithm does it use?

Any pointers will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Weird! I created some greyscale images with the intensity ranges on the left and auto-levelled them and got the ones on the right but I can't see what the algorithm is:

```
Input     Levelled
-----     --------
0-64      0-255
0-128     0-255
0-192     0-255

64-255    64-255
128-255   121-255
192-255   164-255

64-192    126-255
100-150   255 (solid white)
90-160    255 (solid white)
80-170    204-255
```

---

On a more constructive note, you can achieve something similar with **ImageMagick** which is easily installed on a Mac with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Then, supposing you had this print:

[image]

You could use:

```
magick print.jpg -auto-level result.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: So a range between 90 - 160 turns the whole image just plain white?

Comment: @SilverMonkey Yes, weird!